Competitors on the marketplace
I'm trying to make model of market/marketplace. Currently creating model for two goods-competitors: situation when one product pulls some demand from another and we want to know specific cause produced this pull. Basic assumption is lowering the price of the first product drops demand of the second one and vice versa.
So, I'm trying to make simulation or the model of the market. Throughout the process I've found my pipeline probably overcomplicated and ambiguous.
Is there some related material like libraries/articles/researches I could check? Hard to find any information on this topic (market simulation)
